# How to get the corresponding module path for a thread on a remote process in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using

```
HANDLE hThreadSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
```

To get the threads in the system, and then by checking the corresponding pid, i gather all the threads of a particular process and open handle to each of them.

My question is, how can i get the module path that corresponds to this thread, just like process hacker? Meaning lets say this thread's start address is pointing to xxx.dll, how can i find the name of this xxx.dll?

I tried using `GetModuleFileNameEx` but this doesn't work with thread handle and basically doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: use `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemExtendedProcessInformation` instead `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` and look for `Win32StartAddress` for thread;

Comment: @RbMm Any difference with using ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress with NtQueryInformationThread? And after getting the start address, i assume the easiest way is to find the start and end address of every module, and check if the start address is inside which one right? No easier approach?

Comment: i write about *NtQuerySystemInformation* but not about *NtQueryInformationThread*. for use *NtQueryInformationThread* you need first **open** thread, then do this call with *ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress*. when *SystemExtendedProcessInformation* simply return this information for you. different is HUGE

Comment: *find the start and end address of every module, and check if the start address is inside which one right?* - yes. correct. and all this have sense only for debug/system utilites. if somebody use *_beginthreadex* for instace - you got crt dll adress instead "real" thread entry. anyway thread only relative related to some module

Comment: Does the `Win32StartAddress` point to the *user-defined* function that is passed to `CreateThread()`, or does it point to the *system-provided* start function that `CreateThread()` uses internally to initialize the thread before then calling the user's function?